# In NeoVim/Vim, how to change the default keyboard layout for all modes except for insert?

Tags: neovim

I've been trying to map my `ğ` and `ü` keys to `[` and `]` keys. By using your usual Vim config methods like `map`, `langmap` etc. plugins don't respect these keys, no matter where I put these options to maybe affect the order via remap etc. So my next mission is to change my layout so that Vim sort of starts with that layout, sees these keys as what they're mapped to. The problem is that I can't find an easy way to change the default keyboard layout only for Vim.

There's an option of changing the layouts system-wide on Vim insert mode enter, insert mode leave etc. but that might change my layout on other applications too

There's the `keymap.vim` file type for `:set keymap` option, which works, but only for insert mode. I just need it the other way around. Is there a way to do it with configs and some custom additional files instead of going into NeoVim's default files and changing them, because I don't like that

Here are my mappings:

```lua
vim.o.langmap = "ğ[,ü],Ğ{,Ü}" vim.o.langremap = true

vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'ğ', '[', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'ü', ']', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'Ğ', '{', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'Ü', '}', {remap = true})
```

I've tried only using the langmap region, I've tried only keymap region, I've tried both. I've used them in init.lua at the beginning, and also tried moving them in a lua file in the after folder. Doesn't work.

The reason why remap doesn't work might be due to this bug:
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3018

Langremap apparently doesn't work properly outside of ASCII characters, so the only way I can think is changing default keyboard layout for Vim/NeoVim. If you know a way then I'd appreciate it